# async.each/forEach third parameter(callback) is triggered after each interval

Tags: node.js, loops, asynchronous

Hi
I have function that accepts an two arrays and callback function, I am iterating over one of the arrays using async.each(and tried async.forEach and both have same result), everything works fine but the callback that I am receiving as the parameter, which is sent as the third parameter is triggered after the first iteration. Here is my code.

> ```
> function itemLikes(instruments,likes, finalCallback){
> var items = [];
> if(instruments.length >= 1){
>     async.forEach(instruments, function(instrument,cb){
>         if(likes){
>             if(likes.indexOf(instrument._id.toString()) !== -1){
>                 instrument.liked = 1;
>                 cb(items.push(instrument))
>             }
>             else{
>                 cb(items.push(instrument))
>             }
>         }
>         else{
>             cb(items.push(instrument))
>         }
>     }, function(err){
>         finalCallback(items)
>     })
> }
> else{
>     finalCallback(items)
> }
> ```
>
> }

This is what I understood from the documentation, but my finalCallback is triggered right after my first iteration completes.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: Hi it seems that you are passing the same likes as an array while you initially defined likes as a function

Comment: @VivekBajpai, I changed the name of the function for brevity, I guess I should not have done that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the callback that receiving as the parameter (finalCallback()) is triggered after the first iteration is because asyc.each()'s callback (cb) is called with a non-null value.  When it's called with a non-null value, async.each()'s final callback gets called which then calls your finalCallback().  You need to do something like this:

```
if(likes){
  if(likes.indexOf(instrument._id.toString()) !== -1){
    instrument.liked = 1;
    items.push(instrument);
    cb()
  } else{
    items.push(instrument);
    cb()
  }
} else{
  items.push(instrument);
  cb()
}
```

It seems like your logic above can be simplified as following:

```
if(likes && likes.indexOf(instrument._id.toString()) !== -1){
    instrument.liked = 1;
}
items.push(instrument);
cb()
```

Comment: Right, I am stupid to completely overlook the part where we execute callback with null or no parameters, Thanks a lot